# Login to Google using different usernames and passwords?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm developing a blog poster software and in that software, there is a text area that my user writes the content of a blog post, and two text boxes for specifying username and password.
Now I want to login with the specified authentication information into Google quickly. Google API doesn't ask me for authentication data and it seems to me that Google doesn't implement the ability to login with custom username. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Does your blog poster use Google Blogger or other blogs?

Comment: Yes I'm using Google Blogger.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is that you want user can log in your software by enter their username and password in the text box of your app. And your app can authenticate user by call some Google API. But this is improper, and Google does not support this.

What you need is OAuth 2. By authorized by Google user via OAuth, you can call Blogger API v3 to to create new blog posts, edit or delete existing posts, and query for posts that match particular criteria. [The Google official docs](https://developers.google.com/blogger/) have given detailed reference.

So follow [this document](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using) and I think you'll get to be clear about it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of OAuth 2 and I've already written the necessary code for authentication via OAuth.